# In Gatsby starter blog, how to increase number of latest posts from 3 to 20 in home page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am starting to use Gatsby [Minimal Starter Blog by LekoArts](https://minimal-blog.lekoarts.de/) and [Github repo](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-starter-minimal-blog). Currently only 3 latest posts can be displayed in the home page. Can i know how to increase it like from 3 to 30. I don't see any settings for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's defined in the graphql query in [homepage-query.tsx](https://github.com/LekoArts/gatsby-themes/blob/master/themes/gatsby-theme-minimal-blog-core/src/templates/homepage-query.tsx):

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($formatString: String!) {
    allPost(sort: { fields: date, order: DESC }, limit: 3) {
      nodes {
        slug
        title
        date(formatString: $formatString)
        excerpt
        timeToRead
        description
        tags {
          name
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

which is used by `gatsby-node.js` in [gatsby-theme-minimal-blog-core](http://gatsby-theme-minimal-blog-core) (a dependency).

```
const homepageTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/homepage-query.tsx`)
```